# How to make the below markup has-form.li as a last child in php?

Tags: wordpress, themes, zurb-foundation, nav

I'm trying to tweak a Wordpress child theme: https://github.com/schikulski/gromf which edits the parent theme Roots: http://roots.io/

How to make the below Zurb [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html#built-in-components) markup has-form.li as a last child in php?

```
<li class="has-form">
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Find Stuff">
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
      <a href="#" class="alert button expand">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The existing php that I got to play with:

https://github.com/schikulski/gromf/blob/master/lib/nav.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the child/parent theme relationship would cause issues with this method, but I  usually use the [`wp_nav_menu_objects`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) hook.

```
function nav_menu_add_last_class( $items, $args ) {

    $i = count($items);
    while($items[$i]->menu_item_parent != 0 && $i > 0) {
        $i--;
    }
    $items[$i]->classes[] = 'has-form';

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'nav_menu_add_last_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I'm confused what I should do next. What file should I copy & paste your code into? Do I need to create a file called has-form.php?

Comment: @PhilD Sorry, this snippet should go anywhere in your `functions.php` file.  WordPress processes `functions.php` before rendering the page, and this file can contain "hooks" that allow you execute code at various steps during the page rendering process.

Comment: Looks like this is the php that I need to tweak:

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <?php if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
              wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'right'));
        endif; ?>


How to append this into above as last child <li> ?

<li class="has-form">
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Find Stuff">
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
      <a href="#" class="alert button expand">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

Comment: Posting code in this thread got too messy. Please check the pen I created for the rest of this comment

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKEna